# Less variables set in _theme.less are being override elsewhere

Tags: magento2, theme

I'm attempting to change the button color in my magento theme. In my `app/design/frontend/JK/PPC/web/css/source/_theme.less` I have the following:

```
/*
 * Buttons
 */
@button__color: @color-gray20;

/*
 * Navigation
 */
@navigation__background: @color-white;
```

The navigation background changes fine, but the button color doesn't change. I've checked in dev tools and I notice it's being overriden by `.action.primary`

[image]

I have nothing in my own code that overrides this. The only files I have under `web` are `web/css/source/_blocks.less` (my custom blocks styles), `_theme.less` and `_styles.less` which contains:

```
@import 'source/lib/_lib.less';
@import 'source/_sources.less'; 
@import 'source/_components.less';
@import 'source/_blocks.less';
```

My theme is based on the blank theme. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question I should have been overriding:

```
@button-primary__background: @color-black;
@button-primary__color: @color-white;
```